# Mongo script optimize nested find queries on big databases

Tags: mongodb

I have two mongo databases that contains both some collections.

I have to update all the items of one collection and to use some values of this collection to find and update items of a collection from the other database. Here is a pseudocode that illustrates what I am doing in my mongo script:

```
db1 = db.getSiblingDB('db1')
db2 = db.getSiblingDB('db2')

db1.collection1.find().forEach(function(item1) {
  db1.collection1.update({_id: item1._id}, {$set: {field1: new_value}});

  db2.collection2.find({field2: item1.filter}).forEach(function(item2) {
    db2.collection2.update({_id: item2._id}, {$set: {field1: new_value}});
  }
})
```

The problem is that my first collection has ~ 100000 entries and that my other collection 50000 entries, so it takes a lot of time to execute.

How could I improve my script?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to decrease the execution time (30 minute to 1 minute) by creating an index on the column(s) that I use as a filter (db2.collection2.field2 in my example).

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/

Answer (score 1):

I will give  you  some  suggestion  about  this  query  .May not be suitable for your scene, please correct me.

```
db1 = db.getSiblingDB('db1')
db2 = db.getSiblingDB('db2')
##  find({},{data:1})  
## {}  first stage  is used  for  reduce the total number of data.
## {data:1}  second  stage only  get the field  you need to be used  for  Calculation
db1.collection1.find({},{data:1}).forEach(function(item1) {
  ##  it is better  to use  updateMany()
  db1.collection1.update({_id: item1._id}, {$set: {field1: new_value}});

  ##  if  the value  is  same  please use  update many  
  db2.collection2.updateMany({field2: item1.filter},$set: {field1: new_value}});

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it did not improve the execution time.

Comment: create  index  on the query  field  is the most effective way .